# when and why do use JumboEnumSet

Tags: java, collections, enums

I have suffered about JumboEnumSet, but did not find much information about.
when and why do we use JumboEnumSet.Please can anyone explain about JumboEnumSet?

Comment: Private implementation class for EnumSet, for "jumbo" enum types (i.e., those with more than 64 elements).   http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/JumboEnumSet.html

Comment: I think you should ask the question you're facing instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use it explicitly - it's just an implementation detail. Basically, when an enum is small, `EnumSet` can use a very efficient representation of the enum as a single `int` or `long` (I forget which) with one bit per member. When it has more elements than that representation allows, `JumboEnumSet` is used instead.

You don't need to worry about this - just use the members on `EnumSet` and you'll be fine. Just be aware that if your enums go over a certain size, then enum sets become more expensive and less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it.

You *can't* use the class directly because it is declared as package private.  And you shouldn't, since it is described in its javadoc as a "private implementation class".